# hive exclude values from query

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, boolean-logic

I have some data that looks like

```
name        state
mary        florida
mary        NULL
john        alabama
mary        NULL
salt        texas
```

I want to grab results that dont include mary's with a null state. When i try

```
select name, state from my table where (state is not null and name = 'mary')
```

This only gives me all the mary's that has a state connected to it.

what im looking for in the expected results is

```
name        state
mary        florida
john        alabama
salt        texas
```

Comment: It's very likely that what you think as `null`s are `blank spaces`.  What happens when you execute `select * from tbl where state is null`?

Comment: those are nulls, i edited my posted

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query.  But you can try this `select * from tbl where length(nvl(state,'')) > 0 and name = 'mary'`

Comment: @jumpman8947 you question is confusing,  the result what you are showing, is it the output of your query? or this is the result you want as part of your query?

Answer (score 0):

Select all except name='mary' with state is NULL:

```
select name, state from my table where NOT (state IS NULL AND name = 'mary');
```

Or the same according to the [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (the negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations):

```
select name, state from my table where (state IS NOT NULL) OR (name != 'mary');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, state from my table where state is not null
```

The above query will provide you the expected results

and its a good practice to use coalesce function to the column which has null val es when you are not getting expected result

```
select name, state from my table 
where coalesce(state,’default’) is not default;
```